# How to format one block element and one inline element?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

My assignment is to recreate the content on a wikipedia page in visual studio. I made separate divs for the intro paragraphs, the contents box, and the sidebar. I can't get the sidebar to float to the side of the intro text - it floats right but stays under the intro text. Is there an easy flexbox solution maybe? Any ideas?

I tried floating the contents box to the left and the sidebar to the right, but can't figure out how to move the sidebar up.

```
<body>
    <h1>Sara Bareilles</h1>
    <hr>
    <h4>From Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia</h4>
    <div class="content">
    <div class="intro">
        <p> <strong>Sara Beth Bareilles</strong> (/bəˈrɛlɪs/; born December 7, 1979)[1] is an American singer-songwriter and actress.</p>
        <p>Bareilles has sold over one million albums ...as a bestseller.[5]</p>
    </div>
    <div class="contentsBox">
        <div class="tocTitle"><strong>Contents</strong>[hide]</div>
        <ul class="contentsSection">
            <li> 
                <a href="#Life and career">
                <span class="contentsNum">1</span>
                <span class="contentsText">Life and career</span>
                </a>
            </li></ul>
 </div>
    <div class="sidebar" id="sidebar">
        <span class="sidebarTitle"><b>Sara Bareilles</b></span>
        <div class="photobox">
            <img class="photo" src="440px-Sara_Bareilles.jpg" alt="Sara Bareilles sitting at the piano and singing" width="200px">
            <p class="caption">Bareilles performing at the Troubadour in West Hollywood, California in October 2015</p>
        </div>
        <div class="infoItem">
            <span class="infoItemTitle"><b>Born</b></span>
            <span class="infoItemText">Sara Beth Bareilles</span>
        </div>
```

Comment: Could you provide your `css` to figure out how you built it?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not that clear, I made a [`codepen`](https://codepen.io/mrenzodiaz/pen/oNvWPqN?editors=1010) of your code, hope this is what you mean.

https://codepen.io/mrenzodiaz/pen/oNvWPqN?editors=1010